# Cucumber-Hadoop: How to read cucumber feature files from a HDFS location?

Tags: hadoop, cucumber, hdfs, spark-submit

I am using `import cucumber.api.cli.Main` method to call cucumber main method like

```
Main.main(
    Array(glue,gluePath,tag,tagName,plugin,pluginNameAndPath,
        "hdfs:///user/test/hdfs.feature"))
```

Is it possible to read feature files from HDFS location, as it is working with local path?

The way to read hdfs path is

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
val fsDataInputStream = fs.open(new Path("/user/test/hdfs.feature"))
```

which I can cast into Input stream as well, but the issue is Array() accept only string and hdfs reader return input stream as well as FileSystem.
Is there any solution of this problem?

For more reference - 
This problem exists when i use "spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode **cluster**".

It's working fine for "spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode **client**".

Comment: Found the solution of this problem, for reading the feature file we need to use pass file using --files and use sqlContext.sparkContext.addFile(x) to add into cluster and SparkFiles.get(x) to get the path where is it stored then use it like normal file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of my question
provide all the your feature files using --files like

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue cbi_ops --driver-memory 10G 
--executor-memory 5G --executor-cores 5 --num-executors 5 \
--jars $jars_path \
--files $files_path \
--driver-class-path xx.jar \
--class RunnerMain \
xx.jar \
"-g" "xx.stepdefinitions" \
"-t" "@functional-test,@regression-test" \
```

add all the files in your code using

```
sqlContext.sparkContext.addFile(x)
```

then use in Array through SparkFiles.get like:

```
Array(glue,gluePath,tag,tagName,plugin,pluginNameAndPath,plugin,pluginNameAndPathJson,
            SparkFiles.get("ingestion-mc-ris-r2d-inc.feature"))
```